# How to include output data in pep8 format docstring

Tags: python, pep8

A standard pep8 docstring according to the style guide for python could look like the following:

```
"""Function description

Keyword arguments:
keyword_arg_1 -- description
keyword_arg_2 -- description
"""
```

However I see nothing in the standard for returned output data, and I consider this to be a vital part of the definition of a function. i.e I want to document every variable preceded by a `return` statement.

What is a good standard way to also provide a description and type for each returned function output in python?

Comment: Do you use an IDE? An IDE (like PyCharm) will provide excellent code formatting and also documentation support

Comment: I use Pycharm and have pep8 syntax correction enabled. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using pycharm, just define the function and put 3 `"` right after `def`, press enter and it autogenerate the docstring for you, including return data. You can also select upto 5 docstring format, by goto `Settings > Tools > Python Integrated Tools > Docstring format`. I dont know if we can customize it or not, but I think what they're providing is sufficient
[image]

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much!